# Missing image when saving image from canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas

I use this code to save images in Javascript :

```
function saveImage() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myPicture');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, 460, 600);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    img.src = "http://localhost/upload/abc.jpg";
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,_item.width(),_item.height());
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
}
```

When i click button save image:

```
$("#save").on('click', function () {
    var rawImageData = saveImage();
    $(this).attr('download', 'your_pic_name.jpeg').attr('href', rawImageData);
});
```

**However the result I get is white image.**
And I click on the save button again (ie 2 times) then is now right result. how do I can just click one time only?
Thank you.

Comment: Strange ... you are calling `saveImage()` and you obviously expect it to mysteriously return some `rawImageData`. Yet, your function `saveImage` doesn't return anything ... on top of that you are using `new Image()` twice.

Comment: my code is missing and I've added

Comment: Hm ... `the result I get is white image`?? You are drawing a white rectangle on a (probably) white canvas? It's like having a flag with a white eagle on white ground

Comment: I desired result is an picture containing url image, also color white is background

Comment: I still don't understand the meaning of the `img` variable in your saveImage function. It's used nowhere and it is in no relation to the canvas ...

Comment: img is parameter for function drawImage

Answer (score 0):

It is because the first time you click, anchor doesn't have image data url... You may set the url and forget about the click event.

```
  //$("#save").on('click', function () {
    var rawImageData = saveImage();
   $(this).attr('download', 'your_pic_name.jpeg')
          .attr('href', rawImageData);
  //});
```

OR

```
  $("#save").on('click', function () {
    var rawImageData = saveImage();
   /*$(this).attr('download', 'your_pic_name.jpeg')
          .attr('href', rawImageData);*/
        window.location=rawImageData;
  });
```

OR alternatively, you need [this file](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) to use following code

```
   var canvas = document.getElementById('myPicture');
 function saveImage() {
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var img = new Image();
   ctx.rect(0, 0, 460, 600);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
   img = new Image();
   img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
   img.src = "http://localhost/upload/abc.jpg";
   //  ctx.fill...
   return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
}
  $("#save").on('click', function () {
    var rawImageData = saveImage();
    var png= Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas , true);
  });
```

PS: I don't see where you feel canvas with the image...int the `saveImage` function